# Targeting something inside of a div without a class?

Tags: html, css

Say I had: the following code. How could I select only the third div and style the 2 paragraphs inside assuming there are no classes or id's?

```
<div>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</div>    
<div>
  <h2></h2>
  <input>    
<div>
  <p></p>
  <input>
</div>    
<div>
  <h4></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to type in the CSS file for instance:
div:last-of-type

also if you need to target the second div you can get it by:
div:nth-of-type() in between the parances you can type the number you want to target

Answer (score 0):

For inheritable properties, you may just specify the number of the child of the `<div>` element. e.g. `div:nth-child(3)`

For non-inheritable properties, you need to have a higher level of specificity to target the `<p>` elements. e.g. `div:nth-child(3) p`

To check if the property is inheritable, you may check the list [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/propidx.html).

```css
/* for inheritable properties such as color*/
div:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}

/* for non-inheritable properties such as border*/
div:nth-child(3) p {
  border: thin solid skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> First
  </h1>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <h2> Second
  </h2>
  <input>

  <div>
    <p> Third
    </p>
    <input>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4> Fourth
    </h4>
  </div>
```